# JMESPath filter with >1 match ANDING

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, jmespath

I saw the [ORING post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37945318/jmespath-json-filter-with-multiple-matches); this should cover ANDING; I struggled with this one.

Given this while loop:

```
while read -r resourceID resourceName; do
    pMsg "Processing: $resourceID with $resourceName"
    aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id="$resourceID" --output table > ${resourceName}.md"
done <<< "$(aws emr list-clusters --active --query='Clusters[].Id' \
--output text | sortExpression)"
```

I need to feed my loop with the ID AND Name of the clusters. One is easy; two is eluding me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to end up with a output looking like this from `list-clusters`:

```
1  ABCD 
2  EFGH
```

In order to feed it to `describe-cluster`, then you should create a [multiselect list](https://jmespath.org/examples.html#filters-and-multiselect-lists).

Something like:

```
Clusters[].[Id, Name]
```

This is actually described in the user guide about [text output format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html#text-output), where they show that:

> ```sh
> 'Reservations[*].Instances[*].[Placement.AvailabilityZone, State.Name,
> InstanceId]' --output text
> ```
>
> Gives
>
> ```
> us-west-2a      running i-4b41a37c 
> us-west-2a      stopped i-a071c394 
> us-west-2b      stopped i-97a217a0 
> us-west-2a      running i-3045b007 
> us-west-2a      running i-6fc67758
> ```

<sup>*Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-output-format.html#text-output*</sup>

---

So you should end up with

```sh
while read -r resourceID resourceName; do
    pMsg "Processing: $resourceID with $resourceName"
    aws emr describe-cluster \
      --cluster-id="$resourceID" \
      --output table > ${resourceName}.md"
done <<< "$(aws emr list-clusters \
  --active \ 
  --query='Clusters[].[Id, Name]' \
  --output text | sortExpression \
)"
```

Comment: Perfect; I was making it too difficult